# Use targets.LoadbalancerTarget to create RecordSet in AWS CDK with Python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cdk

I want to create a RecordSet with an alias from a Loadbalancer, for which I use the

```
aws_cdk.aws_route53_targets as targets
```

This does not work, but I'd like it to work and am not understanding the error:

```
    self.r53_record_set = r53.RecordSet(
        self,
       "rcs-record-set",
         record_type=r53.RecordType.A,
        record_name=subdomain,
        zone=loadbalancer.load_balancer_canonical_hosted_zone_id,
        target=r53.RecordTarget.from_alias(targets.LoadBalancerTarget(loadbalancer))
    )
```

The Error I get -

```
RuntimeError: Passed to parameter props of new aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53.RecordSet: Unable 

to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53.RecordSetProps
├──  Failing value is an object
│      { '$jsii.struct': [Object] }
╰──  Failure reason(s):
    ╰─ Key 'zone': Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53.IHostedZone
        ├──  Failing value is a string
        │      '${Token[TOKEN.823]}'
        ╰──  Failure reason(s):
            ╰─ Value does not have the "$jsii.byref" key
```

I should not get this error? As the "Token" is should be accessed during the `cdk deploy`?

This works fine (Cfn):

```
    self.r53_record_set = r53.CfnRecordSet(
        self,
        "rcs-record-set",
        hosted_zone_id=loadbalancer.load_balancer_canonical_hosted_zone_id,
        name=subdomain + str(loadbalancer.load_balancer_canonical_hosted_zone_id),
        type="A",
        alias_target=r53.CfnRecordSet.AliasTargetProperty(
            dns_name=loadbalancer.load_balancer_dns_name,
            hosted_zone_id=loadbalancer.load_balancer_canonical_hosted_zone_id
        )
    )
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check the documentation and compare the types of the props to the types that you're passing. `zone` expects a zone, not an ID.

Comment: thank you <3 i guess its been a long enough day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gshpychka pointed out: I missed, that I needed a hosted zone instead of an id.

```
    self.r53_hosted_zone = r53.HostedZone(
        self,
        "rcs-hosted-zone",
        zone_name=hosted_zone_name 
    )
    self.r53_record_set = r53.RecordSet(
        self,
        "rcs-record-set",
        record_type=r53.RecordType.A,
        record_name=subdomain,
        zone=self.r53_hosted_zone,
        target=r53.RecordTarget.from_alias(targets.LoadBalancerTarget(loadbalancer))
    )
```